# How to prevent AutoCompleteTextView's drop down from hidden immediately when click action is performed on the drop down item

Tags: android

I have the following `AutoCompleteTextView`

[image]

It is implemented as follow :-

```
public class MyAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.setOnItemClickListener(getMyOnItemClickListener());
    }

    private OnItemClickListener getMyOnItemClickListener() {
        return new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                ...
            }
        };
    }
```

When user clicks on the drop down item, `onItemClick` function will be triggered. At the same time, the drop down UI will be hidden immediately automatically.

I was wondering, how can I let drop down UI from showing all the time even when the click action performed?

Comment: override `dismissDropDown` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this method in your class and comment the first line. @Override

```
public void dismissDropDown() {
 //   super.dismissDropDown();
}
```

with overriding this method and commenting out super.dismissDropDown(). it will override the default behaviour.